# Sha256 is not providing 16 byte array

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography, hex

Im using the following method to generate pass phrases for aes encryption.

MY aes needs 16 bytes for a key.

Here is how I am getting my key

```
    public  byte[] sha256digest16(String[] list) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();
        for(String s: list){
            digest.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[]  b = digest.digest();

        return String.format("%0" + (b.length) + 'x', new BigInteger(1, b)).getBytes("UTF-8");

    }
```

However, it is 64 bytes. How I can I get this method to return a 16 byte string

**EDIT**
The main reason Im doing this is because my python code is

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256


myHash = SHA256.new()
myHash.update("265jMeges")
print myHash.hexdigest()
```

which outputs

```
917ef7e7be4a84e279b74a257953307f1cff4a2e3d221e363ead528c6b556edb
```

where is the java output of is

```
efbfbd7eefbfbdefbfbd4aefbfbdefbfbd79efbfbd4a257953307f1cefbfbd4a2e3d221e363eefbfbd52efbfbd6b556eefbfbd
```

for the same string. Why are they different?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using SHA512 if you're getting 64 bytes? Either way, no current hash gives a result as short as 128 bits, so you'll just have to truncate the output.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can truncate that output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-256 returns 32 bytes by default (`256 / 8 = 32`), not 16. The normal way to use a part of a hash is to use the first (leftmost) 16 bytes of the resulting hash. You can do this by applying the Java [`copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5b%5d,%20int%29) method on the result of SHA-256.

Please use a real hexadecimal encoder to *display the result* (not to return a value, you don't need any `String` instances at all). Using `BigInteger` is error prone and may add or remove bytes.

Try for instance:

```
public static byte[] sha256digest16(String[] list) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.reset();
    for(String s: list){
        digest.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    // so you have 32 bytes here
    byte[]  b = digest.digest();

    // you can return it directly or you can cut it to 16 bytes
    return Arrays.copyOf(b, 16);
}
```

For display as hexadecimals use:

```
public static String tohex(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", data[i] & 0xFF));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or use one of the hex encoders of the Apache commons codec, Bouncy Castle or Guava.

Comment: So you are displaying 64 hex characters, as there are 2 characters per byte, you simply display 32 bytes, i.e. the full output of the hash. What's there to see? Changed your code in my answer, see if this fits you.

Answer (score 0):

You're formatting the result bytes as hex, which multiplies the bit occupancy by a factor of 2. You'll never get 16 bytes that way. Get rid of the String.format() line and just return the result of the digest() method. I expect you're repeating the process elsewhere which is doubling it again,